# How to get the class from a callable

Tags: php, callable

In this situation:

```
$callable1 = "\somenamespace\someclass::somefunction";
$callable2 = array('someclass', 'somefunction');
$callable3 = 'somefunction';
$callable4 = array($someInstance, 'somefunction');
```

Is there a way I can reliably extract the namespace and class (if any) from a callable, no matter the format in which it is defined?

Comment: Are you wanting the function to tell you the namespace and class?

Comment: I want something like `$class = getClassFromCallable($callable);` and want `$class` to be `someclass`

Comment: @Greggg what if the callable is an anonymous function?

Comment: Just null would be fine then, or false.

Comment: @mpapec that doesn't work, `get_class` expects an object not a callable.

Comment: Do you mean pass in one of your four variables and it determines what the class name is given it's format (and data)?

Comment: @JaredFarrish yes :) so results for 1 through 4 (for getting class) would be: 1; `someclass`, 2; `someclass`, 3; `null` or `false` (as `get_class()` returns `false` this would probably be better, and 4; an identical response as `get_class($someInstance)`

Comment: Why don't you just write a function to parse your examples based on their format?

Comment: well, yes, that could work, but I was hoping there'd be a way without manual interpretation of the callable. The callable itself is pretty much a direct pointer to something, which could be backtraced to return partial information (function name, class name, namespaces).

Comment: Create a `ReflectionFunction`, then `getClosureScopeClass`... https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following class seems to do exactly what you need:

[CallableReflection.php](https://gist.github.com/Raphhh/6203942)

It looks like the namespace extraction is missing. You can add it yourself with PHP's reflection:

[ReflectionClass::getNamespaceName](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getnamespacename.php)

Comment: Just gave this a try, it returns the class with the namespace, which actually isn't bad for what I'm intending to use it for. Quite a class though! Guess my request was harder than I anticipated. Cool, thanks. :)

Comment: If the answer works for you, please be so kind and accept it. So it's no longer in the list of unanswered questions.

Comment: Fine, I don't say this because it's my answer ;) Many new users don't know how this site works. But I see, you're not really new..